# Force a variable to be an integer CVXPY

Tags: python, python-3.x, cvxpy

I'm trying to force a variable to be an integer (integer constraint) using cvxpy in Python, but result keeps being a float:

```
from cvxpy import *

Fi = Int() 
Or = Int()

constr = [Fi <= 3000,
                 Or <= 3000,
                 Or >= 1000,
                 1.25*Or - Fi >= 0,
                 Fi >= 0,
                 Or >= 0]

obj= Maximize(50000*Fi + 25000*Or)

prob = Problem(obj, constr)
prob.solve()

print ("Status: ", prob.status)

print ("Fi: ", Fi.value)
print ("Or: ", Or.value)

print ("Obj: ", obj.value)
```

Result:

```
Status:  optimal
Fi:  2999.9999999
Or:  2999.99999989
Obj:  224999999.992
```

What can I do to force it?

I have tried too:

```
Fi = Variable() 
Or = Variable()

constr = [Fi <= 3000,
                 Or <= 3000,
                 Or >= 1000,
                 1.25*Or - Fi >= 0,
                 Fi >= 0,
                 Or >= 0,
                 Fi == Int(),
                 Or == Int()]
```

Fi and Or are variables. Not just numbers.

Comment: @nico I have tried too `Fi=Variable()` and add constraint `Fi == Int()` and i'ts not duplicate. In that question they're not using cvxpy

Comment: On your constraint, 1.25*. How do you expect the result to be Int? http://www.cvxpy.org/en/latest/tutorial/intro/index.html

Comment: @ADL Fi can't be more than de 125% of Or. It doesn't imply that Fi has to be float

Comment: @Aleharu, I had the same problem (with many more variables)! I think cvxpy stores solutions as `numpy.matrix` variables to save space, which kind of casts every solutions as a float. I simply thresholded my output to cast as int:

`np.matrix([0 if abs(el)<.99999 else 1 for el in x.value])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem (with many more variables)! I think cvxpy stores solutions as `numpy.matrix` variables to save space, which kind of casts every solutions as a float. I simply thresholded my output to cast as `int`. This should work for you:

```
Fi_val = int(Fi.value)+(1 if (Fi.value - int(Fi.value)) >0.9 else 0)
Or_val =  int(Or.value)+(1 if (Or.value - int(Or.value)) >0.9 else 0)
```

There are better ways to get the fractional part of an integer `x` than `x-int(x)` (such as `Math.modf(x)` and `numpy.modf(x)`), but this requires no package imports.

Note that you can threshold at 0.9999999999 rather than just 0.9. The output of cvxpy seems to be an `int` up to almost the full precision of a numpy matrix float.

(If anyone can make this idea more precise, please do).

Comment: Hi Zach, it's true. The result is the nearest float to an int. I just round it.

Comment: It looks like the latest version of CVXPY has addressed this problem directly. See https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/advanced/index.html

Comment: With the `integer=True` keyword argument, I guess you mean. Good update @user1757436